# Ввод данных в input

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, как реализовать следующую идею. Есть input в который через запятую вводятся числа (возраст, который нужно записать в какую-то переменную для дальнейшей работы) и в label(к примеру) выводится: "Количество человек: ..".

На примере: Введите возраст: 24, 22, 10 (24 года, 22 года, 10 лет).
И выводится -> Количество человек: 3

Comment: Поделить по запятой и посчитать: `input.value.split(',').length`. При пустом вводе, правда, выведет `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```js
function result(data) {
  // Убираем пробелы и превращаем в массив
  var arrayData = data.replace(/\ /g, '').split(',');
  
  // Считаем количество записей
  if(data == ''){var data_length = 0}else{var data_length = arrayData.length};
  
  // Выводим количество записей
  console.log('Количество человек: '+data_length);
  // Выводим список чисел
  console.log('Возрасты: '+arrayData);
  //Выводим каждое число
  for(var i = 0; i < data_length; i++){
    console.log('Возраст №'+i+': '+arrayData[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="old">
<button onclick="result(document.querySelector('#old').value)">Количество людей</button>
```

Но технику следует доработать, так-как пользователь может ввести буквы и другие значения